# ArrayList remove(0) when size > 0

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to get the first item in a ArrayList items using items.remove(0), which works fine till the items.size() is 1,
        at this point the code below returns empty string. I tired 2 different ways but do not know why it is returning "" when I 
        expect it to return the last remaining item when items.size > 0. 
Step over using Android Studio, the debugger steps over BOTH return lines in my second code. Never seen this before. Please help solve this.
        Thank you

```
        String item = "";
    if (items.size() > 0) {
        item =  items.remove(0);
    }
    return item;


    if (items.size() > 0) {
        return items.remove(0);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: "Step over using Android Studio, the debugger steps over BOTH return lines in my second code." - This doesn't look right to me - can you do a clean build and then try to debug?

Comment: To what I understand you are looking for the first occurrence of an object in the list using the `remove(Object O)` method (I might be wrong, but I don't see any other why you would want to use the `remove` method over the `get` method). 

Based on that, de realize that the remove() method returns a boolean. but again passing 0 as the argument doesn't make much sense. Are you sure it's not a typo?

Comment: Clean Porject, Rebuild Project did not help. I am using remove(int location) which returns String. I want to get the item as well as remove it from the list.

Comment: Learning programming, I found that the code was being called twice, I deleted the second call and that fixed the problem. I feel small, sorry to waste your time of this post, being new to SO, should this post  be deleted? thx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the .get() method?

```
String item = "b" // items.size() = 1
if(items.size() > 0) {
   item = items.get(0);
} else {
    item = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
The code was being called twice, once by an object constructor and another but a method in same object, so as soon as the first call "by the constructor" return finishes, the second call executes and since the condition changed, the second return gets executed.
Basically my bad coding logic created the problem. after deleting one of the calls. the code worked fine.